# How do you efficiently return the order of an increasing index?

Tags: r

I have the following index vector:

```
TestVec = rep(c(6,8,9,11,18), each = 10)
```

This reads `c(6, 6, ..., 6, 8, 8, ..., 8, 9, 9, ..., 9, ...)`.

I would like to convert this vector into `c(1, 1, ..., 1, 2, 2, ..., 2, 3, 3, ..., 3, ...)`

---

**Try**

I have improvised a quick-and-dirty method, as follows:

```
sapply(TestVec, function(x) {which(x == unique(TestVec))})
```

This works fine, but this takes a lot of time in a large dataset.

Is there any efficient way to improve?

Comment: `cumsum(!duplicated(TestVec))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match(TestVec, unique(TestVec))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
as.numeric(as.factor(TestVec))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Requiring `data.table`:

```
rleid(TestVec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one,

```
c(1, cumsum(diff(TestVec) != 0)) + 1
```